# How to get Time at which data is posted in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am making an App which contains **RecyclerView** with **CardView**.
When the data is posted in **Firebase**, it should show the time in **RecyclerView**. 
For e.g.  Posted 4 hrs ago, posted few mins ago , etc...

How to achieve it?

Comment: is the data being posted to firebase from your app?

Comment: Yes the data is posted through the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `auto-created` metadata in Firebase about when a node was created, updated, deleted or who created it, etc. If you have a need for such data, you need to create your own mechanism. You can add it either by writing the local timestamp or by writing a [server-side timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#server-timestamps).

Comment: Thankyou i will try it

Comment: Ok and keep me posted.

Comment: And can u provide me a code to send notification when a new data is posted please

Comment: This is basically another question. In order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question, so me and other users can help you. Did my answer helped you fir the initial question?

Comment: Yes it helped i will post the other question ty

Comment: By clicking the blue button `Ask Question` from the top right corner.

Comment: It says that we are no longer accepting questions from this account

Comment: In this case, you need to wait till you they can accept

Comment: Ohk then. Thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

It is very possible. It would have been best if you provided a code snippet for edit suggestions. 
Use mine in this case. I will make a post with a title and time.

In your adapter where you firebase post is processed, add the time like this

public class post {

```
private String Title;
private long Time;

public post(String title){
    Title = title;
    Time = new Date().getTime();
}

public post(){}

public String getTitle() {return Title;}
public void setTitle(String title) {this.Title = title;}
public long getTime() {return Time;}
public void setTime(long time) {this.Time = time;}
```

}

now when you make your post, you will have values title and time in milliseconds and you will not have to call time. It is added automatically.

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference(staticPath)
                .push()
                .setValue(new post(Title));
```

when showing your data on recyclerview, you will get the data normally

```
viewHolder.showPosts(model.getTitle(), model.getTime());
```

and set time to in the example you showed like

```
timeText.setText(DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(time,
                    System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS));
```

Use your phone to test and make two posts at different times, it will display time in the format (4 minutes ago). if the time is older than 6 days, it will display the date.

Comment: Hey this didnt worked for me. It only displays. 1 JAN 1990. ON EACH Post

Comment: @user7593511 this is because the device has the wrong date. use your phone. Displaying that date means it is working and that is the earliest date on milliseconds

Comment: is the node that you are fetching having title="title" and time=875456423 a big number

Comment: no , can we do one thing that instead of taking time from user can we get it from firebase server and display it in required format

Comment: no, you have to register the time a post was made. Its not inbuilt

Comment: this is what i use in my app, please post your implemented code so i can suggest your edit